# how should I correct this program from head first java?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn java by reading head first java recently.

Here's a program list on page 39. In order to understand it better,  I am trying to type in and run it by using eclipse. 
Part of the program show as follow,

```
public class GuessGame {
Player p1;
Player p2;
Player p3;
public void startGame() {
p1 = new Player();
p2 = new Player();
p3 = new Player();
int guessp1 = 0;
int guessp2 = 0;
int guessp3 = 0;
boolean p1isRight = false;
boolean p3isRight = false;
```

This is not the whole program, but you may see the problem occurs  "Player cannot be resolve as a type".
So how should I correct this program?

Comment: This is taken from the book?  Look at preceeding/following pages for the `Player` class.

Comment: Do you have a class `Player` in the code?

Comment: Class Player is in same package? If not you must import it and make sure it has a public constructor.

Comment: Post the rest of your code please. All of it. All classes etc....

Comment: @Blaine Read the first part of the question.  This is taken from a book, page 39.  I assume this is everything available on page 39.  The original poster needs to look at the other pages for the implementation of the `Player` class.

Comment: @nhgrif the OP also says, "This is not the whole program". All I'm saying is post the rest of the program you have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code...

`Player` is a class, so you need to have a `Player` class defined. If you do, it should be in the same package. Otherwise, you need to import the package that `Player` is in.

I'm assuming that you don't have a `Player` class defined. You could simply do:

```
class Player{

}
```

You add this by creating a new class and adding the above code. Make sure you add the class to the same package you are working out of now.

Comment: You are right. I accidentally defined the class Player in a new package, and I didn't notice that . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Player p1` you are actually creating a `p1` reference that is supposed to point to an object of `Player` class which is not there in you case. Down in your program when you do `p1 = new Player()` you are creating a Player `object` (`new Player()`) but compiler can't see `Player` class hence the error. So, you will have to create a `Player` class so that the compiler know what `Player` really means

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the class player.
Add this to your code.

```
class player{

}
```